# MySQL and Regex on INT

Tags: mysql, regex

This query should return 4 rows but returns 1 with the ID of 62983.  Any reason why?

```
SELECT *
    FROM sims_user_role_maps surm
    JOIN sims_role sr ON surm.role_id = sr.id
    WHERE 
        surm.user_id = 118730
        AND sr.organization_id REGEXP 62978|62981|62982|62983
```

**SP Call**

```
call schools_remove_for_user('f155ec0e-b9ce-11e1-a1fa-001cc4565d26', '62966|62969|62983')
```

**SP**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `schools_remove_for_user`(
    user_id NVARCHAR(255),
    school_ids LONGTEXT
)
BEGIN

DECLARE sims_user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;

SELECT u.sims_id 
INTO sims_user_id 
FROM user u 
WHERE u.id = user_id;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

DELETE FROM sims_user_role_maps
WHERE 
        user_id = sims_user_id
    AND role_id IN (
                SELECT role_id 
                FROM(
                    SELECT surm.role_id 
                    FROM sims_user_role_maps surm
                    JOIN sims_role sr ON surm.role_id = sr.id
                    WHERE 
                            surm.user_id = sims_user_id
                        AND sr.organization_id REGEXP school_ids) 
                A);

END
```

Comment: are you sure those other rows exist? 78, 81, 82? And have a user_id = 118730 in the surm table?

Comment: This is a dynamic string, and yes they do belong to that user ID.  I even removed the last ID 62983 and it is still bringing back that only row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the user_id in the delete statement.  I added the table name as the prefix.

```
DELETE FROM sims_user_role_maps
WHERE 
        sims_user_role_maps.user_id = sims_user_id
    AND sims_user_role_maps.role_id IN (
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not place the regular expression inside quotes, so `|` works as  [bitwise OR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or).

The correct syntax is `AND sr.organization_id REGEXP '62978|62981|62982|62983'`. You can also  consider `sr.organization_id IN (x, y, z)` which is better if you are just trying to match specific integers.

Comment: This works directly when I execute the SQL but in a stored proc it doesnt.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: Are you sure that the SP doesn't have some other problem?